# Tic Tac Toe in PyQt4

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe, pyqt

I'm working on learning Python, and this is my second GUI project using PyQt.  I've played it a few times to test it and it seems to work.  It isn't anything clever; the computer just picks randomly.  Any feedback would be quite welcome.

```
import sys
import random
import time
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Tic(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Tic,self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50,50,360,400)
        self.setWindowTitle('Tic Tac Toe')
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('favicon.png'))

        self.winner = ''
        self.board()
        self.new_game()

    def board(self):

        newAction = QtGui.QAction('&New game', self)
        newAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+N')
        newAction.setStatusTip('Make a new game')
        newAction.triggered.connect(self.new_game)

        # add an exit feature
        exitAction = QtGui.QAction('&Leave', self)
        exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAction.setStatusTip('Leave the app')
        exitAction.triggered.connect(self.close_application)

        self.statusBar()

        # menu part of exit feature
        mainMenu = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('&File')

        # new game feature
        fileMenu.addAction(newAction)

        # exit
        fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)

        # set up game board  
        self.btn0 = QtGui.QPushButton('', self)   # first argument is the text
        self.btn0.clicked.connect(lambda: self.clicked(0, self.playerCoin))  
        self.btn0.resize(100,100)
        self.btn0.move(20,280)

        self.btn1 = QtGui.QPushButton('', self)   
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.clicked(1, self.playerCoin))  
        self.btn1.resize(100,100)
        self.btn1.move(130,280)

        self.btn2 = QtGui.QPushButton('', self)  
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.clicked(2, self.playerCoin))  
        self.btn2.resize(100,100)
        self.btn2.move(240,280)

        self.btn3 = QtGui.QPushButton('', self)   
        self.btn3.clicked.connect(lambda: self.clicked(3, self.playerCoin))  
        self.btn3.resize(100,100)
        self.btn3.move(20,170)

        self.btn4 = QtGui.QPushButton('', self)   
        self.btn4.clicked.connect(lambda: self.clicked(4, self.playerCoin))  
        self.btn4.resize(100,100)
        self.btn4.move(130,170)

        self.btn5 = QtGui.QPushButton('', self)  
        self.btn5.clicked.connect(lambda: self.clicked(5, self.playerCoin))  
        self.btn5.resize(100,100)
        self.btn5.move(240,170)

        self.btn6 = QtGui.QPushButton('', self)   
        self.btn6.clicked.connect(lambda: self.clicked(6, self.playerCoin))  
        self.btn6.resize(100,100)
        self.btn6.move(20,60)

        self.btn7 = QtGui.QPushButton('', self)   
        self.btn7.clicked.connect(lambda: self.clicked(7, self.playerCoin))  
        self.btn7.resize(100,100)
        self.btn7.move(130,60)

        self.btn8 = QtGui.QPushButton('', self)  
        self.btn8.clicked.connect(lambda: self.clicked(8, self.playerCoin))  
        self.btn8.resize(100,100)
        self.btn8.move(240,60)

        # list of taken move positions
        self.taken = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        self.takenBy = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

        self.btnDict = {  0 : lambda x : (self.btn0.setText(x), self.btn0.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Times', 60))),
                 1 : lambda x : (self.btn1.setText(x), self.btn1.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Times', 60))),
                 2 : lambda x : (self.btn2.setText(x), self.btn2.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Times', 60))),
                 3 : lambda x : (self.btn3.setText(x), self.btn3.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Times', 60))),
                 4 : lambda x : (self.btn4.setText(x), self.btn4.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Times', 60))),
                 5 : lambda x : (self.btn5.setText(x), self.btn5.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Times', 60))),
                 6 : lambda x : (self.btn6.setText(x), self.btn6.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Times', 60))),
                 7 : lambda x : (self.btn7.setText(x), self.btn7.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Times', 60))),
                 8 : lambda x : (self.btn8.setText(x), self.btn8.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Times', 60)))
                     }

        # this should always be last
        self.show()

    def clicked(self, btnval, player):
        if self.taken[btnval] == 0:
            # update free moves & the screen
            self.btnDict[btnval](player)
            self.taken[btnval] = 1
            # update who-owns-what to check if there's a winner
            if player == 'X':
                self.takenBy[btnval] = 'X'
            else:
                self.takenBy[btnval] = 'O'
            print self.takenBy
            self.test_for_winner()
            self.computer_move()
            self.show()
        else:
            pass

    def new_game(self):
        item, ok = QtGui.QInputDialog.getItem(self, "Choose X or O", 
                                              "Would you like to play as X or O?", ('X','O'), 0, False)
        if ok and item:
               self.playerCoin = item

               if self.playerCoin == 'X':
                   self.computerCoin = 'O'
               else:
                   self.computerCoin = 'X'

    def computer_move(self):
        # find moves the computer can make
        legal_moves = []
        for j in range(9):
            if self.taken[j] == 0:
                legal_moves.append(j)

        # for now, pick a random valid move
        btn = legal_moves[random.randint(0,len(legal_moves)-1)]

        # call the clicked method
        time.sleep(1)
        if self.taken[btn] == 0:
            # update free moves & the screen
            self.btnDict[btn](self.computerCoin)
            self.taken[btn] = 1
            # update who-owns-what to check if there's a winner
            if self.computerCoin == 'X':
                self.takenBy[btn] = 'X'
            else:
                self.takenBy[btn] = 'O'
            print self.takenBy
            self.test_for_winner()
            self.show()
        else:
            pass

    def test_for_winner(self):
        # enumerate possible winner configurations
        winning_configs = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]]
        for j in range(8):
            if self.takenBy[winning_configs[j][0]] == 'X' and \
               self.takenBy[winning_configs[j][1]] == 'X' and \
               self.takenBy[winning_configs[j][2]] == 'X':
                self.winner = 'X'
            if self.takenBy[winning_configs[j][0]] == 'O' and \
               self.takenBy[winning_configs[j][1]] == 'O' and \
               self.takenBy[winning_configs[j][2]] == 'O':
                self.winner = 'O'

        # if there is a winner, report it and end the game        
        if self.winner == 'X' or self.winner == 'O':
            msg = '{} won the game!  Would you like to play again?'.format(self.winner)
            choice = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self,'Game Over!', msg,
                                            QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | QtGui.QMessageBox.No)

            if choice == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
                self.close()
                self.__init__()
            else:
                sys.exit()

        # if there's a draw, handle it here
        if self.winner == '' and sum(self.taken)==9:
            msg = 'It was a draw!  Would you like to play again?'
            choice = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self,'Game Over!', msg,
                                            QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | QtGui.QMessageBox.No)

            if choice == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
                self.close()
                self.__init__()
            else:
                sys.exit()

    def close_application(self):
        # add functionality to see if we want to exit
        choice = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self,'Exit','Are you sure you want to exit?',
                                            QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | QtGui.QMessageBox.No)

        if choice == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
            sys.exit()
        else:
            pass

def main(): 
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Tic()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you didn't use the advices given in [your previous question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/146186/84718) to use a loop to build the buttons?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger Yes, sorry. I didn't want to sort out the button locations within the for loop, since it would probably need modulo to determine which row and column was under consideration. But since this seems to be a frequent suggestion, I'll be sure to implement it in the next go around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked through your code and I have a few comments.

**Major Bugs**

1. `new_game()` function doesn't reset the game

Clicking the new game menu item or pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> does not reset the game board or the moves.

This can be solved by adding some code to the new_game() function that resets the 'coin' inside the buttons, as well as moving some code from your `board()` so that it executes every time `new_game()` is called. Shown below.

```
    def new_game(self):
        #### CODE ADDED #####
        #This resets the board
        [self.btnDict[key]("") for key in self.btnDict]
        self.winner = ''
        #### END CODE ADDED ####

        #### CODE MOVED FROM board() ####
        # list of taken move positions
        self.taken = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        self.takenBy = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        #### END OF CODE MOVED FROM board() ####

        item, ok = QtGui.QInputDialog.getItem(self, "Choose X or O", 
                                          "Would you like to play as X or O?", ('X','O'), 0, False)
        if ok and item:
               self.playerCoin = item

               if self.playerCoin == 'X':
                   self.computerCoin = 'O'
               else:
                   self.computerCoin = 'X'
```

**Minor Bugs** (these don't break the game but probably should be changed)

1. After winning (or losing) the game if the player wants to play again then the program should just call the `new_game()` function instead of closing and reopening the window.

Calling `new_game()` instead of closing and reopening the window exposes another bug that is fairly easy to fix. The bug is that when a player wins and chooses to play a new game the computer gets an extra move at the beginning. This can be solved by having `test_for_winner()` return a bool as in the following code.

```
def test_for_winner(self):
    # enumerate possible winner configurations
    winning_configs = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]]
    for j in range(8):
        if self.takenBy[winning_configs[j][0]] == 'X' and \
           self.takenBy[winning_configs[j][1]] == 'X' and \
           self.takenBy[winning_configs[j][2]] == 'X':
            self.winner = 'X'
        if self.takenBy[winning_configs[j][0]] == 'O' and \
           self.takenBy[winning_configs[j][1]] == 'O' and \
           self.takenBy[winning_configs[j][2]] == 'O':
            self.winner = 'O'

    # if there is a winner, report it and end the game        
    if self.winner == 'X' or self.winner == 'O':
        msg = '{} won the game!  Would you like to play again?'.format(self.winner)
        choice = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self,'Game Over!', msg,
                                        QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | QtGui.QMessageBox.No)

        if choice == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
            self.new_game()
            return True
        else:
            sys.exit()

    # if there's a draw, handle it here
    if self.winner == '' and sum(self.taken)==9:
        msg = 'It was a draw!  Would you like to play again?'
        choice = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self,'Game Over!', msg,
                                        QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | QtGui.QMessageBox.No)

        if choice == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
            self.new_game()
            return True
        else:
            sys.exit()
    return False
```

Now you just need to modify the `clicked()` function so that it responds to the bool passed back from the `test_for_winner` function

```
def clicked(self, btnval, player):
    if self.taken[btnval] == 0:
        # update free moves & the screen
        self.btnDict[btnval](player)
        self.taken[btnval] = 1
        # update who-owns-what to check if there's a winner
        if player == 'X':
            self.takenBy[btnval] = 'X'
        else:
            self.takenBy[btnval] = 'O'
        print self.takenBy
        if not self.test_for_winner():
            self.computer_move()
        self.show()
    else:
        pass
```

These changes now completely enable the 'new game' option.

2. The player's move doesn't appear until the computer makes its move.

This bug is actually tied to the synchronous nature of the qt GUI. The way to fix this is to implement your functions using asynchronous signals. That is a more advanced topic and beyond the scope of this code review; it is, however, a fundamental part of good game programming and well worth your time to study.

Comment: Thanks so much for the thorough review!  May I ask if you have suggestions of where I can learn some about asynchronous signals with Python/PyQt?  Having to wait for the computer to play was something I noticed but wasn't sure how to fix.